# specify default plot settings on matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Here a code that draws a line with specific settings of the plot, such as the major and minor grids and x limits

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

idx1 = -3
idx2 = 3
x = np.arange(idx1, idx2, 0.01)
y = np.sin(np.pi*x)/(np.pi*x)

minorStep, majorStep = 0.25, 0.5
major_ticks = np.arange(idx1, idx2, majorStep)
minor_ticks = np.arange(idx1, idx2, minorStep)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
#ax.set_ylim(0.6, 1)
ax.set_xlim(idx1, idx2)
ax.set_xticks(major_ticks)
ax.set_xticks(minor_ticks, minor = True)

ax.plot(x, y)
ax.grid(True, which = 'both')
plt.show()
```

What I would like to write is a code on my first jupyter cell in order to specify these default plot settings for all the plots on my jupyter project.

Could you help me, please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4301140 refer here ..Also there are many links like this one...

Comment: http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/customizing.html

Comment: For non-style settings, create a function that takes your figure / axis as an argument and applies what you need

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to make easy and efficient plots on Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42996834/how-to-make-easy-and-efficient-plots-on-python)